# Nodejs filter data and send it as response

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of data I have a function that filter the array get the data I want and send it as a response.

The problem is the function sends the 1st array only, 
for example here is the data:

```
[
    {
        "name": "2 Hours 30 Min (2.5 Hours)",
        "price": 20,
        "rewardPoints": 50,
        "priceInPoints": 1000,
        "minutes": 150,
        "id": 8
    },
    {
        "name": "5 Hours",
        "price": 40,
        "rewardPoints": 100,
        "priceInPoints": 1800,
        "minutes": 300,
        "id": 7
    }
]
```

Code:

```js
getRequest(timeProducts)
  .then(response => {
    const result = response.data.result;
    result.forEach(data => {
      if (data.pointsPrice != null) {
        res.json({
          name: data.name,
          price: data.price,
          rewardPoints: data.points,
          priceInPoints: data.pointsPrice,
          minutes: data.minutes
        });
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(errorMessage => {
    res.json(errorMessage);
  });
```

What I get is :

```
{
    "name": "2 Hours 30 Min (2.5 Hours)",
    "price": 20,
    "rewardPoints": 50,
    "priceInPoints": 1000,
    "minutes": 150,
    "id": 8
}
```

But I want all.

What am I doing wrong here?

And what's the best approach to even make this function better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You send response in the first iteration of forEach.
Before you send response, you should construct the desired result, and then send.

You can use filter and then map methods of array.

```js
getRequest(timeProducts)
  .then(response => {
    const result = response.data.result
      .filter(data => data.pointsPrice)
      .map(({ name, price, points, pointsPrice, minutes }) => ({
        name,
        price,
        rewardPoints: points,
        priceInPoints: pointsPrice,
        minutes
      }));
    res.json(result);
  })
  .catch(errorMessage => {
    res.status(500).json(errorMessage);
  });
```

Also better to send 500 error code in the catch block.

Comment: data example of @mohamed adel is: data =  {[50,2 Hours 30 Min (2.5 Hours),20,1000,150],
[100,5 Hours,40,1800,300],
[150,10 Hours,75,3600,600]}

Comment: where is name, price, points, pointsPrice, minutes  in data example ?

Comment: i know, but data·example of @mohamed adel is: data = {[50,2 Hours 30 Min (2.5 Hours),20,1000,150], [100,5 Hours,40,1800,300], [150,10 Hours,75,3600,600]}

Comment: @linthertoss  his data is an array of objects.

Comment: @mohamed-adel can you also try this answer?

Comment: @mohamedadel I edited your question, because it had "need more details" flag. If you think my edit is not correct, you can edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can only send one `res.json` per request, so after the first iteration of your `forEach` your response is sent back and the request is done. So you need to map your data and save it to a variable, and then send that variable as a response:

```
getRequest(timeProducts)
            .then(response => {
                const result = response.data.result
                const dataToSend = []
                result.forEach(data => {
                    if (data.pointsPrice != null) {
                        dataToSend.push({
                            name: data.name,
                            price: data.price,
                            rewardPoints: data.points,
                            priceInPoints: data.pointsPrice,
                            minutes: data.minutes,
                        })
                    }
                });
                res.json(dataToSend);
            })
            .catch(errorMessage => {
                res.json(errorMessage)
            });
```

Or, instead of using a `forEach`, use a `filter` and map over it directly in the `res.json` function:

```
getRequest(timeProducts)
            .then(response => {
                const result = response.data.result
                res.json(result.filter(data => {
                    if (data.pointsPrice != null) {
                        return {
                            name: data.name,
                            price: data.price,
                            rewardPoints: data.points,
                            priceInPoints: data.pointsPrice,
                            minutes: data.minutes,
                        }
                    }
                    return false
                 }));
            })
            .catch(errorMessage => {
                res.json(errorMessage)
            });
```

Comment: Great thanks. It works. this is the best way to do it? just asking

Comment: I edited my answer with a more eloquent way to do it in my opinion.  I prefer maps vs forEach if possible

Comment: the second code returns all the data not the filtered ones like your 1st anwer

Comment: @mohamedadel Sorry I forgot to include the if check, I updated the answer, it will work correctly now

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
 getRequest(timeProducts)
            .then(response => {
                const result = response.data.result
                response.json(result.filter(data => {
                    return data.pointsPrice 
                }));
            })
            .catch(errorMessage => {
                res.json(errorMessage)
            });
```

Comment: @mohamedadel what is your  input  data ?